# Trying to Query a DB in C# and then store it to a variable

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my main goal: I want a user to be able to enter a computername in a text box and I have a table in my db that has computernames and ipaddresses in it. So i want to be able to do something like this when I query the db...
"select ipaddress from computername where computername = 'textbox1.text'". This way when a user types in a computer name it will then look in the db and use the ipaddress to map to the pc.

so far I am just trying to get results back from the db into the textbox1. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace testwf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

                        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10-nuerp-006acdst;Database=Rert;User Id=reports;Password=Password");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cs.Open();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10-nuerp-006acdst;Database=Rert;User Id=reports;Password=Password
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cs.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from station", cs);
            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            //cs.Open();
            dr.Read();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cs.Open();
                command.ExecuteReader();
                textbox1.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(1).ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
                            }

            MessageBox.Show(dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
            cs.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your EXACT code?  If so, you're missing some items on the first line in your `button1_Click` (`SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10-nuerp-006acdst;Database=Rert;User Id=reports;Password=Password` should be `SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10-nuerp-006acdst;Database=Rert;User Id=reports;Password=Password");`.  Also, from what I've gathered, using input from the user like that can lead to some bad things happening.  I'd suggest having something that they can choose from without letting them enter any text.

Comment: Whats the problem with it? You run it, what happens? By the way, it could just be how you have copied it, but the editor on this site has a syntax highlighter, and you should look at how your question looks. The syntax has clearly screwed up at the bottom - suggests to me that your code doesn't compile anyway.

Comment: Does your query currently work?  Because this code as is won't even compile.

Comment: Why would you store an address in your database that can change periodically if your site uses DHCP? Getting an IP address for a computer name is better performed using DNS. You should store only the computer names in your database.

Comment: I agree with @JamieSee, if you want to display the IP Address you should work on retrieving it from querying the workstation as it is connected to the network at the time the user is querying, otherwise your information could be out of date. I.P addresses are usually only Leased for x-amount of time and its only ever Printers that are ever given static IP Addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example, refer to http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html

```
 private void btnFind_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            // Open connection to the database
            string ConnectionString = "server=xeon;uid=sa;"+
                "pwd=manager; database=northwind";
            con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            // Set up a command with the given query and associate
            // this with the current connection.
            string CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName" +
                                 "  FROM Employees" +
                                 " WHERE (LastName LIKE @Find)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            // Add LastName to the above defined paramter @Find
            cmd.Parameters.Add(
                new SqlParameter(
                "@Find", // The name of the parameter to map
                System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, // SqlDbType values
                20, // The width of the parameter
                "LastName"));  // The name of the source column

            // Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
            // from the text field
            cmd.Parameters["@Find"].Value = txtFind.Text;

            // Execute the query
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Fill the list box with the values retrieved
            lbFound.Items.Clear();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                lbFound.Items.Add(rdr["FirstName"].ToString() +
                " " + rdr["LastName"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Print error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close data reader object and database connection
            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my first post so I may have messed up when uploading the code, when I run my code the form loads fine but when I click my button sand expect to see the ip appear in the txtbox an error pops up that says invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Answer (score 0):

This code replaces what's in your `button1_click` event:

```
using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"Server=10-nuerp-006acdst;Database=Rert;User Id=reports;Password=Password"))
{
    cs.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from station", cs))
    using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            textbox1.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(1).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

As for "uelreader"s answer: It's much easier to add SQL parameters like that:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameterName", someVariableOrConstant);
```

The type is determined automatically and conversion stuff is done by the framework. Use urlreader's version only if you need to set the type and length explicitly.

Comment: The code above does display the record in the messagebox but for some reason it is not displaying it in the textbox. Any Ideas?

Comment: Any idea how to get the record into the textbox<?

Comment: Well, is there a value in the second column that's queried? Your code (and thus my code above) displays different column values. The text box gets the value of column 1, the message box displays the value of column 0. Try to change the index for `GetSqlValue` from 1 to 0 in the assignment of the text box value.